# Customizing TabWidget in SDK 1.5, API 3

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm aware that API 3 doesn't allow a view to be set for a tab, but I still need to modify the TextView displayed as the indicator. I'd also like to change the Drawable for the tab, but I don't see a way to do it without a custom tab view as allowed in 1.6, API 4.

Working with this generic example below, is there way to retrieve the TextView and modify its properties or change the drawable?

```
       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
       TabHost.TabSpec spec;

       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("nearby")
                      .setIndicator("Nearby Activity")
                      .setContent(R.id.nearby_list);                
       tabHost.addTab(spec);        

       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("friends")
                  .setIndicator("Friends & Favorites")
                      .setContent(R.id.friends_list);
       tabHost.addTab(spec);        

       tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("nearby");
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the icon:

```
 .setIndicator("Friends & Favorites",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myTabIcon))
```

to change the TabBackground Drawable::

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt( index of tab ).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mytab_Newbackground);
```

to retrieve the Textview, check Francesco's sample

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt( index of tab );
TextView tv = (TextView)v.getChildAt(1); 
Log.d("Tab's text = ",tv.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Tabwidget is a normal ViewGroup I think you should access to the 
all its children.
Something like this should work:

```
   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
....
...


@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        int count = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i); //Should be a relative layout
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.getChildAt(1); //At position 0 should be the ImageView
            Log.d("onTabChanged",tv.getText().toString());
        }

    }
```

Maybe, you have to play with the indexes position to find the right View.